# Looking for good physics/maths/algorithm learning resources for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, physics

I have been playing around with JavaScript and Canvas for a while.
Very often when I dissect a code people have put on the web, it is really hard to understand the logic and algorithm behind the code if the code is poorly commented.

I would like to apply physics and maths to my code.
Are there any good articles, resources hub or books I could learn more about it?

I am aware of few good physics library out there such as Box2D. However I am hoping to learn the basics rather than using the library blindly.

Comment: Perhaps helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[algorithm]+[math]+books

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foundation HTML5 Animation with JavaScript by Keith Peters and Billy Lamberta is a really good book. I just started reading it. So far it is great. It covers many formulas and in-depth explanation on that. [http://www.amazon.com/Foundation-HTML5-Animation-JavaScript-Lamberta/dp/1430236655](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430236655)

You could have a pretty thorough read on Google Books.
http://books.google.co.nz/books?id=KZTIFYMLShYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=foundation+html5+animation+with+javascript&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XZhiT7q3L8eaiAfh0_DfBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I think the Processing community has very good learning resources when it comes to advanced animation with physics and maths.

Check out this tutorial on vector.
http://processing.org/learning/pvector/

It is really useful and easy to read.
Definitely recommend everyone to look out for (soon to be released) The Nature of Code book by Daniel Shiffman - http://natureofcode.com/

Looks promising.